# Win11 Photo Viewer: Does not delete to recycle bin/trash?

Tags: windows, photos

I plug in a USB drive. Am browsing jpeg files with the Windows native photo viewer app. I delete one (because I think I have a dupe of it).

Turns out there is no dupe.

And the deleted file is not in the recycle bin!

(There is an option in Photo Viewer to confirm on deletes -- that does NOT meet my needs. Why does "delete" everywhere in Windows use the recycle bin, but not photo viewer?)

Comment: I think because the object is on a non-local drive. I see (in xPlorer2) a message "Are you sure you wish to permanently delete?"

Comment: Most OSes do this for drives with non-native formats like FAT, because they don't respect the recycle bin/trash structure.

Comment: You can try to recover the image from the USB device, *if it has not been subsequently overwritten*. See https://www.easeus.com/resource/usb-drive-data-recovery.html or https://www.cnwrecovery.com/html/fat32.html . for example. Initially, deletion just changes how a file is marked, not its contents. Make a copy of the USB to reduce chance of data loss.

Answer (score 2):

USB devices (USB drives) are usually not the same structure as the Recycle Bin on a modern computer.

So then when you delete a file it will not go into the recycle bin.

Normally (as I posted earlier) there is a message "Do you wish to permanently delete). However, it appears that Photo Viewer does not honour this convention. I cannot find anything to the contrary on this.